# MongoDB skip() and limit() on a sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, sql-limit

If I run following query on a sharded mongodb cluster and query is a scatter/gather type.

```
find({"product": "laptop"}).sort({"year": 1}).skip(15).limit(5)
```

Will the and SKIP + LIMITS (combination) be applied on mongos or on individual shards (i.e. mongod) ?

or mongos sends limit(20) to each shards i.e. sum(skip+limit) to optimize the query and then also apply 
skip(15).limit(5) to the gathered results before returning to client

Comment: What is the point of the question? Do you want to know if MongoDB will "limit" the results returned from each shard or whether the "limitting" is actually happening on the `mongos` router? What exactly is the concern? Are you thinking your entire collection is being sent to the `mongos` router? I really don't think any of these should be a concern to you at all. If on the other hand you think **performance** of your query is slow, then just come out and say that. Using `skip()` and `limit()` is **not optimal**, and the documentation does say that explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to your doubt. You can read the entire doc section [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/), but the part you are interested in is this one:

> ## How mongos Handles Query Modifiers
>
> #### Sorting
>
> If the result of the query
>   is not sorted, the `mongos` instance opens a result cursor that “round
>   robins” results from all cursors on the shards.
>
> #### Limits
>
> If the query limits the size of the result set using the
>   `limit()` cursor method, the mongos instance passes that limit to the
>   shards and then re-applies the limit to the result before returning
>   the result to the client.
>
> #### Skips
>
> If the query specifies a number of records to skip using the
>   `skip()` cursor method, the `mongos` cannot pass the skip to the shards,
>   but rather retrieves unskipped results from the shards and skips the
>   appropriate number of documents when assembling the complete result.
>
> When used in conjunction with a `limit()`, the `mongos` will pass the
>   limit plus the value of the `skip()` to the shards to improve the
>   efficiency of these operations.

If you are worried about performances, the best thing you can do is getting the query plan using `explain`. On this same doc, it is specified that:

> For more information on how the work of aggregation is split among
>   components of a sharded cluster query, use `explain:true` as a parameter
>   to the `aggregation()` call. The return will include three json objects.
>   **mergeType** shows where the stage of the merge happens (“primaryShard”,
>   “anyShard”, or “mongos”). **splitPipeline** shows which operations in your
>   pipeline have run on individual shards. **shards** shows the work each
>   shard has done.